# shake: dependency on shared library that is built internally in the project

Tags: shake-build-system

In my project, I want to build a shared library `libfoo.so` first, then build some test programs that use this shared library. For the test programs, if I use need

```
need libfoo.so
```

then they will be rebuilt every time `libfoo.so` is updated. Instead, I want to build the test programs after `libfoo.so` exists and the header files change (or build the test programs for the first).

The dependency on the header files can be done through `gcc -MMD -MF` and `needMakefileDependencies`.

How do I express the dependency on the existence of `libfoo.so` without forcing rebuild every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand properly, you build a library `libfoo.so` which also produces some header files in order to build itself. You want to compile some programs which make use of those header files, but depending on `libfoo.so` itself causes your programs to rebuild if it changes, which is excessive.

Assuming that, the answer is `orderOnly ["libfoo.so"]`. This construct ensures that `libfoo.so` is built before continuing (and thus that the header file is correct), but does not actually depend on it. The main use of `orderOnly` is when you want "a lot of stuff" to be built, and then you scan it (e.g. with `gcc -MMD -MF`) to figure out exactly which pieces to depend on.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I can let shake write a temporary file with fixed content every time `libfoo.so` is built and let the test programs depend on this temporary file.  This temporary file marks the existence of `libfoo.so`.